# 18 gauge wire on 18 branches

Tags: electrical, fire-safety

I have 12 gauge wire to a 20amp circuit going around a bedroom.   Then I have a fixture with 18 G9 LED bulbs on a chandelier.  Do I just wire all hot leads to the hot 12 gauge and wire all the whites together which puts all the LEDs in parallel?  I mean, I don't see draw on any wire going high at all unless I put them in parallel I guess.  Thoughts?

I'm hoping this is the right gauge in the chandelier since it's from China and they don't typically follow code and only go for cheap.

Comment: LED lamps use low current, so 18 gauge wire is safe in that respect. The only question would be about the physical durability and temperature range of the wire if used inside walls.

Comment: only 12 guage is in walls.  18 guage is in the lamp's area for wiring as it has room to wire as well and a little room in junction box too of course.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, connect the hot leads to the hot #12 and the white leads to the white #12 neutral, wiring all the led lights in parallel. You can group or pigtail them.
You need to check the load in the bedroom to make sure you don't overload the circuit but led lights have such low wattage my guess is you'll be ok.

Where did you buy the chandelier, online? Is it approved for use in the area you live in?

Answer (score 1):

NEC 110.2 says that equipment must be "approved".   This means by the local Authority Having Jurisdiction (AHJ, the town electrical inspector).

It is the policy of essentially every electrical inspector to rubber-stamp any fixture which is listed by Underwriter's Laboratories (UL) or other [Nationally Recognized Testing Lab (NRTL)](http://www.intertek.com/knowledge-education/partners-in-product-safety/nationally-recognized-testing-laboratories/).  *Note that CE* is not a testing lab.  Neither is FCC, CCC, CCCanything, or  RoHS.*

No credible NRTL mark and file number, you have to sell it to the AHJ.

18 AWG is fine inside a fixture.  I don't suggest trying to put 19 wires under a wire nut, or otherwise abuse/overload connectors.

- If you feel comfortable putting six #18s on a wire nut, then have 4 groups of 4-5-5-4 each with a #18 pigtail, then and gather those four into another wire nut  with a #14 or #12 pigtail.   That pigtails to the ceiling.
- Otherwise group 3 wires to a #18 pigtail (six of these), 3 of these pigtails to a #14 or #12  pigtail (two of these), then join those #12s with the ceiling wires.

Yes, all blacks go together and all whites go together, placing them in parallel.

You would not wire the LEDs in series unless you were using bare emitters and a constant-current driver circuit. (Constant-current very much favors series connection). In that case you would never socket them; the LEDs would be hardwired.

---

* CE stands for "Chinese Excrement".  Not really.  It's a voluntary self-certification for businesses physically in the EU (where they're sueable if they cheat).   Anyone else can slap it on anything with no consequences.